# Django UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: python, django, model

When I am trying to save not unique object I am getting this error:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: event_invitedperson.email,
>   event_invitedperson.event_id

Where and how should I check if record is unique before saving?

My model:

```
class InvitedPerson(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField("")
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('email', 'event')]
```

**model:**

```
class InvitedPerson(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField("")
    event = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use get_or_create method.

```
>>> InvitedPerson.objects.get_or_create(email='gmail@gmail.com', event=event1)
(<InvitedPerson: InvitedPerson object>, True)
>>> InvitedPerson.objects.get_or_create(email='gmail@gmail.com', event=event2)
(<InvitedPerson: InvitedPerson object>, True)
```

So email will associated with multiple event...